# Searching for duplicates in rows with attached datasets from another table

Tags: sql, t-sql, duplicates

I need to delete duplicate records from the table. Syntax: T-SQL (MS SQL Server)

There are two difficulties with it:

1. There are fields containing data that should not affect row comparison
2. There is an additional table linked with the first with "one-to-many" relationships

Example:

```
Table A                 Table B
--------------          --------------
AId - int       <-\     BId - int
A1 - int           \->  AId - int
A2 - varchar            B6 - varchar
A3 - varchar            B7 - varchar
A4 - varchar            B8 - varchar
A5 - int                B9 - int
```

So, any record in Table A contains the fields AId, A1, A2, A3, A4 and A5, and the list of "sub-records": a list of records in Table B where B.AId matches A.AId. For instance, it can be list of purchasing transactions, where Table A contains properties of transaction, such as date/time or client ID, and Table B can represent a list of goods with their prices and amounts.

Once some of the records were duplicated. They have different AId, different BId, different A4, A5, B8 and B9. All other fields should match to make two records a duplicate.

Thus, two records X and Y from A are considered duplicate if:

- X.A1 == Y.A1
- X.A2 == Y.A2
- All the records from Table B with AId == X.AId completely match all the records from B with AID == Y.AId, but excluding (ignoring) B8 and B9 fields

I need to at least get AIDs of such duplicate records, at most to delete those duplicates but left only one copy of the record (doesn't matter which one).

Please tell me if the following clarification is needed. Thank you in advance.

*upd:* SQL Fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/898c8/1

Answer (score 0):

```
Select a1, Count(CompareField) From (Select a.a1 as a1, a.a1 + a.a2 +  a.a3 + b.b6 + b.b7 as compareField from A inner join b on a.AID = b.AID) z Group by z.comparefield
```

This will get you a list of all the duplicates then you could use an outer query to delete the records Delete From a Where AID in (prevquery)

It probably doesn't need to be stated but, MAKE SURE YOU BACK UP THE DATA BASE BEFORE RUNNING YOUR DELETE QUERY. :)

Comment: Thank you, but can you please adjust a fiddle:
http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/898c8/1.

The final output should contain AIDs: 1 and 2.

3 and 4 don't count since there are different values in one of the rows in B7.

Answer (score 0):

The trick is to concat multiple rows from table B to a single string.

For SQL server you can abuse the XML features (can be problematic if there are special characters in the values - others have built-in functions like LIST() in Sybase, which returns a comma-separated list):

```
SELECT AID, A1, A2, A3, (
  SELECT B6, B7
  FROM B
  WHERE AID=A.AID
  ORDER BY B6, B7
  FOR XML RAW
) XML
FROM A
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/898c8/29/0

Now you have a flat table and it's easy to find and delete duplicates (which is left as an exercise for the reader)...